# Why is ManimCE plotting a different graph than the one provided?

Tags: python, manim

I'm trying to create a graph for the function (1+1/x)^x.

I wrote it in python like this:

```
def func(x):
    return pow(1+(1/x),x)
```

I then plotted it like this:

```
graph = axes.plot(lambda x: func(x), color=BLUE, stroke_width=2, x_range=[0,X_MAX])
```

(X_MAX is a variable that equals 1000)

but for some reason Manim is plotting something else.

When I plotted the function in Desmos I got this graph:
[image]

And Manim gave me this one:
[image]

(I know the scales are different the main focus is the hump at the top)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the default smoothing that causes these weird oscillations; basically this happens because the function changes too fast in a (relatively) small interval.

Try either passing `use_smoothing=False` to your call of `plot` -- and/or alternatively, try refining the step size by passing a third number to the `x_range` list.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use small values of dt.

```
class drawgraph(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        axes= Axes()
        def func(x):
            return pow(1+(1/x),x)
        graph = axes.plot(lambda x: func(x),dt = 0.001, color=BLUE, stroke_width=2, x_range=[0,5])
        self.add(axes, graph)
```

Comment: What does dt mean in this case?

Comment: Never mind, upon testing this solution did not work.

Comment: It works in my pc though.. Only after i had tested it, i posted it here.. Maybe the version of manim you are using needs to be updated.. Or maybe you are using not manimce but either manim-cairo or manimgl.